# Square Connect API - update variation endpoint resets Item 'available_online' parameter

Tags: python, square-connect

I'm using the Square Connect API to manage inventory in Square (using an extended version of the Python scripts found here: https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v1/python). The store offers items online, so when creating or updating items, I am setting the 'available_online' flag to true. All is well and the items appear in the online store (store is set up and visible to the public).

However, when I use the endpoint to update a variation of this item (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#put-variationid), the 'available_online' parameter is reset to False and the items disappear from the online store. Is this intended behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Having implemented some additional API functionality, I am observing the same behavior with the Upload Image (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#post-image) and Apply Fee (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#put-itemid-feeid) endpoints. Accessing either of these endpoints resets the 'available_online' flag on an item.  
  
This appears to be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this bug. I've reported it to the API development team. Until this issue is fixed, you can work around it by sending a followup request to the Update Item endpoint to set the `available_for_pickup` and `available_online` fields to their intended values after you edit another component of an item.